# Trait item implementation is missing: `reserve_withdraw_assets`

Tags: xcm, frame, astar, config, traits

I am running the [Astar](https://github.com/ok-Alice/Astar) node locally and pointing to the [astar-frame](https://github.com/ok-Alice/astar-frame/tree/main) repository which is cloned on my local machine. In the `Astar` node repository, I added the [paths-override](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#paths-overrides) method to the point all dependencies of `astar-frame` to the local folder which solved some dependency issues.

When building the `Astar` node using `cargo build --release`, I get the following error:

```
  error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `reserve_withdraw_assets`
    --> /Users/snowmead/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-4038f27d5e4ea2e8/c22e1c4/runtime/polkadot/src/weights/pallet_xcm.rs:47:1
     |
  47 | impl<T: frame_system::Config> pallet_xcm::WeightInfo for WeightInfo<T> {
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `reserve_withdraw_assets` in implementation
     |
     = help: implement the missing item: `fn reserve_withdraw_assets() -> _feps::Weight { todo!() }`
```

Since I haven't modified anything in `astar-frame` [pallet-xcm](https://github.com/ok-Alice/astar-frame/tree/main/frame/pallet-xcm), I believe this might be a dependency issue. And to confirm that this trait item is implemented, we see in the [`pallet_xcm::Config`](https://github.com/ok-Alice/Astar/blob/master/runtime/shibuya/src/xcm_config.rs#L247) trait that it uses [`pallet_xcm::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;`](https://github.com/ok-Alice/astar-frame/blob/main/frame/pallet-xcm/src/weights.rs#L51) which implements the [`reserve_withdraw_assets`](https://github.com/ok-Alice/astar-frame/blob/main/frame/pallet-xcm/src/weights.rs#L239) trait item.

Comment: After some further debugging, it is most likely because `pallet-xcm` is a sub dependency of `polkadot-runtime` which is imported in the [nomination pool pallet](https://github.com/ok-Alice/astar-frame/blob/main/frame/nomination-pool-staking/Cargo.toml#L29). Astar-frame has their own fork of `pallet-xcm` and therefore is conflicting with the `polkadot-runtime`.

Comment: I did such modifications multiple items already, and it just depends what have you overridden. It'd be helpful to see the delta between your modifications and main branch of `Astar`.

We will remove the custom fork of `pallet-xcm` soon, and will also merge the two repos we have into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied a temporary fix which was to rename the `pallet-xcm` dependency to `astar-xcm` in `astar-frame` and `Astar` to avoid dependency conflicts with the `pallet-xcm` subdependency from `polkadot-runtime`.